# Theme development in Liferay

Tags: css, themes, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I'm trying to make a theme for Liferay 6.2 and I have some misunderstandings.

I create new project, choose `theme`, then click `next` and choose `velocity` and `_styled` responsively. But I want to get a standart theme which I can deploy and nothing change in comparison with default theme. I thought I got the point and after that I should copy overriden .css files in _diffs folder. But I don't achieve that. I attached screenshot with my result and I can't understand why I don't have default theme instead. Also I understand that it may be very dumb question but I hope someone would explain it briefly to me. Thanks in advance.[image: My newcreated theme]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the classic theme as base.

Something like:

> property name="theme.parent" value="classic"

in your build.xml will build your project with the theme that comes with LR by default (the classic one).

Comment: When I create classic theme + velocity I get this:
`Error: Could not find mediaLib accelerator wrapper classes. Continuing in pure Java mode.` Any ideas?

Comment: That is not an real problem, most of the time. The "Continuing with pure Java mode" should not stop the process. But, anyway. If you need to discuss this further, better open another topic. As your question was already answered, please mark as answered, people not find your new issue in a comment, just cause they will not look down here..

Comment: I don't want to create another thread so I'll ask here. What exactly should I do to change navbar color? I created classic theme with velocity framework, but I don't know how to find that line which I need to change..

Comment: This is a big problem with the 6.2…thanks god it is better on 7. The thing is that you need to figure out how the CSS is working. There are a lot off classes and hierarchy in their CSS scheme and it takes a while to get used to. You can play around with the dev tools in chrome and Firefox to see them..but basically you just need CSS with higher priority. Normally you write them in your custom.css file. PS: be careful to make changes only inside the diff folder.

Comment: That's a good advice, thank you! But nevertheless, how can I detect the string in css that I need to change? :)

Answer (score 1):

Victor already gave the correct answer. If you're interested in the background: *_styled* is a theme that basically provides the basics for your own theme but doesn't make any assumption on its appearance. If you really want to build your own theme, this is the preferred one to start from. If you only want to tweak a few things from the *classic* theme, start with classic (as Victor says).

Note that classic is not *meant* to be extended (though it works) - contrary to the documentation, the `css/custom.css` file in classic theme is not empty for this reason. This means that you'll need to adopt the instructions for creating a theme and start with *classic*'s own `custom.css` file.

Comment: Could you give a piece of advice where I can read complete tutorial about theme development? May be some brief step-by-step example? What should I do first of all?

Comment: no, as for me, there is no enough information :( Or you learned how to make excellent themes only from that resource?

Comment: *excellent* themes? Not my cup of tea. I can make things look different. If you want them to look nice, you'll have to check with someone else. Liferay offers a one day course for theme development, which might be an option for you

Comment: Could you please give me a link?

Comment: I like this one: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-a-liferay-theme but it is really not enough if you are starting with LR now.

Comment: ...and if you're looking for a link to the 6.2 trainings, [here it is](https://www.liferay.com/de/services/training/6.2/topics)